# Beginning JavaScript - create table

Tags: javascript

I have to create an array using a for loop to produce the numbers 0-24. Then print these numbers in order in a 5x5 "table" using a for loop.

The output should be: `0 1 2 3 4 x 5 6 7 8 9 x 10 11 12 13 14 x... 20 21 22 23 24`

I can't figure out how to create the table.

Here is my code:

```
// Calculate numbers 0-24
var numbers = [];
for (var 0; i < 25; i++) {
    numbers[i] = i;
}


// Create table
for (var row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (var col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
        document.write('<td>' + numbers + '</td>');
    }
    document.write('</tr>');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing the array without any index. Try this instead:

```
var numbers = [];
for ( var 0; i<25; i++)
{
   numbers[i]= i;
}


//Create table
var i = 0;
var table = "<table>";
for (var row=0; row<5; row++)    //Changed from 4 to 5
{
   table += "<tr>";
   for (var col=0; col<5; col++)    //Changed from 4 to 5
   {
      table += "<td>" + numbers[i] + "</td>";    //numbers to numbers[i]
      i++;
   }
   table += "</tr>";
}
table += "</table>";
document.write(table);
```

**Update:** Taking from what @Jon P answered I updated my answer to only write once.

Comment: "calling the array without any pointer" would be better as "accesssing the array without any index". Also, the expression `numbers[row+col]` should be `numbers[row * 5 + col]`.

Comment: Thank you @RobG. I was trying to figure that out. I think my update also fixes that problem

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses, when i edited my code the output still comes up as 1 line("1234567891011..24") instead of 0-4, 5-9, 10-14, 15-19, 20-24. The end table row seems to not be doing anything. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I believe the problem was that it wasn't encapsulated in the `<table></table>` tags. I updated my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a homework assignment so I'll make some suggestions instead of an out right [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/M2Zb4/2/).

Dont use `document.write`.

Create a table stub on the page using HTML and give it an ID. Find out how to get element by id. Find out how to update the inner html of that element. Only update the document once.

Use a tool like Firebug for Firefox or Developer tools for Chrome to inspect what is rendered to the page so you can work out what went wrong (or right).

Start your search for knowledge here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

For an added bonus you may be able to do this without nested for loops with the help of the [% operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

Supremely overkill, but maybe you will find these functions useful!

```
// creates an array that contains a sequence of numbers from 0 to size-1
function range(size) {
    size = Math.max(0, size);
    var result = [];
    while (size--) { result.unshift(size); }
    return result;
}

// splits an array into chunks of a certain size.
function chunk(array, size) {
    if (!array || !array.length || size < 1) { return array };
    return [array.slice(0, size)].concat(chunk(array.slice(size), size));
}

// takes a 2D array and converts it to an HTML table.
function createHTMLTable(table) {
    var html = table.map(function(row) {
        row = row.map(function(cell) { return "<td>"+ cell +"</td>"; });
        row = row.join('');
        return "<tr>"+ row +"</tr>";
    });
    html = html.join('');
    return "<table>"+ html +"</table>";
}

function renderHTML(html) {
    document.write(html);
}

var numbers   = range(25);
var table     = chunk(numbers, 5);
var tableHTML = createHTMLTable(table);

renderHTML(tableHTML);
```